# Regular Expression Substitution with Conditional Replacement in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

My Perl skills are pretty rudimentary and I'm trying to convert dates in a data file loaded in a scalar variable to a four digit year using a regular expression substitution (among other things).

I've got the following to work to add a 20 to all years.

```
$data00 =~ s/^D(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\n/D$1\/$2\/20$3\n/gm;
```

However, the dates include those before 2000.

While searching for a solution I ran across the /e option which said that it evaluates the replacement as Perl code.  However I don't find it listed in all the documentation I've run across and I'm not sure what the syntax would be.

Is there a way to evaluate the $3 match and output 20 if $3 is less than 50 to make 2000 and 19 if not, to make 1997?  I selected 50 because it seemed to be a safe middle ground.

For illustration purposes though I know it's incorrect:

```
$data00 =~ s/^D(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\n/D$1\/$2\/(if($3<50)20 else 19)$3\n/eg;
```

Is the /e even appropriate in this case?

Line examples extracted from huge text file.

```
D04/07/97
D04/14/98
D10/06/99
D10/13/05
D03/04/10
D12/09/10
D01/20/11
D12/22/11
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `/e`, the replacement expression must be a valid Perl expression (i.e. what you could put following `$x =`).

You can use the conditional operator (`?:`) to evaluate an expression differently based on a condition:

```
s/^D(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\n/ "D$1\/$2\/".( $3 < 50 ? 20 : 19 )."$3\n" /eg
```

Note that replacing the delimiter can make things far more readable when many `/` are involved.

```
s{^D(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{2})\n}{ "D$1/$2/".( $3 < 50 ? 20 : 19 )."$3\n" }eg
```

Comment: Thanks blhsing.  Your method fit the flow of my script. I was writing my script so that all the massaging of the data was done in the scalier before the final conversion and output. As I mentioned I'm pretty rudimentary in my Perl skills and your solution I could easily understand.

Comment: @ikegami Thanks for helping to make the answer friendlier and more complete.

Comment: Damn I didn't know enter would post the reply, continuing.

To be honest I couldn't get it to work at first, it took me a bit to realize I had to add the "m" option to the line for it to work.  As in:

`$data00 =~ s/^D(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\n/"D$1\/$2\/".($3<50?20:19)."$3\n"/egm;`

Comment: @tanker, `/m` changes the definition of `^` (and `$`). Normally, it only matches the start of the string. With `/m`, it also matches after a line feed.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) to do this. Use the `strptime()` class method to parse the date into an object, and then `strftime()` to format it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use Time::Piece;

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;

  my $date = Time::Piece->strptime($_, 'D%m/%d/%y');

  say $date->strftime('D%m/%d/%Y');
}

__DATA__
D04/07/97
D04/14/98
D10/06/99
D10/13/05
D03/04/10
D12/09/10
D01/20/11
D12/22/11
```

Output:

```
D04/07/1997
D04/14/1998
D10/06/1999
D10/13/2005
D03/04/2010
D12/09/2010
D01/20/2011
D12/22/2011
```

The regex solution can be simplified by a) choosing a different delimiter and b) using the ternary operator. If you use `/e` then the replacement text needs to be syntactically valid Perl.

```
while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;

  s|D(\d{2}/\d{2}/)(\d{2})|"D$1" . ($2 < 50 ? '20' : '19') . $2|e;

  say;
}
```

**Update:** There's one (possibly important) difference between the two solutions - the cut-off between the 20th and 21st centuries when converting from two-digit years to four-digit ones. The regex solution uses 50 (as mentioned in the original question). The Time::Piece solution uses 69 - and that limit is hard-coded, so there's no way of changing it. For the data in the original question, that makes no difference. But it might matter if you have data with a year between 1950 and 1969.